# Text not displaying value of Var. Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm a beginner, but I'm trying to display the "valueWeWantToGrab" to a text field but is not showing the result.

this is my code to display someone's Instagram follower amount

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var valueWeWantToGrab = ""
var body: some View {
    
    let baseUrl = "http://www.instagram.com/"
    let username = ""
    let url = URL(string: baseUrl + username)!
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
      guard let data = data else {
        print("data was nil")
        return
      }
      guard let htmlString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
        print("couldn't cast data into String")
        return
      }
      print(htmlString)
      let leftSideString = """
      edge_followed_by":{"count":
      """
      let rightSideString = """
      },"followed_by_viewer
      """
      guard
        let leftSideRange = htmlString.range(of: leftSideString)
      else {
        print("couldn't find left range")
        return
      }
      guard
        let rightSideRange = htmlString.range(of: rightSideString)
      else {
        print("couldn't find right range")
        return
      }
      let rangeOfTheData = leftSideRange.upperBound..<rightSideRange.lowerBound
      var valueWeWantToGrab = htmlString[rangeOfTheData]
      print(valueWeWantToGrab) // prints the follower count: 19093
    }
    Text(valueWeWantToGrab)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you declare the variable `valueWeWantToGrab` twice: Once at the top annotated with `@State` and once towards the bottom within the getter function of the `body` variable.
What you actually want to do at the bottom is assigning to the variable declared at the top instead of declaring a new variable by removing `var` from the line `var valueWeWantToGrab = htmlString[rangeOfTheData]`. Doing that, you also have to wrap `htmlString[rangeOfTheData]` with a String initializer (`String()`) as `htmlString[rangeOfTheData]` gives you a value of type `Substring`, not a value of type `String`. This is the result:

```
...
let rangeOfTheData = leftSideRange.upperBound..<rightSideRange.lowerBound
valueWeWantToGrab = String(htmlString[rangeOfTheData])
print(valueWeWantToGrab) // prints the follower count: 19093
...
```

Also, to make your code a little cleaner (though not required to make it work), it might be a good idea to move the code that loads the data to a dedicated method instead of putting it in the getter of the `body` variable (as a general rule of thumb, try to only put UI elements in the `body` of SwiftUI `View`s and do the business logic somewhere else - that will help you to keep your code clean and readable). You can then call the method in the initializer of your `ContentView`. This comes with the benefit that you can then reuse that method elsewhere - for example to implement a refresh button in the future. This is what the final result might look like:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var valueWeWantToGrab = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(valueWeWantToGrab)
    }
    
    init() {
        loadFollowerCount()
    }
    
    private func loadFollowerCount() {
        let baseUrl = "http://www.instagram.com/"
        let username = ""
        let url = URL(string: baseUrl + username)!
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data else {
                print("data was nil")
                return
            }
            guard let htmlString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
                print("couldn't cast data into String")
                return
            }
            print(htmlString)
            let leftSideString = """
      edge_followed_by":{"count":
      """
            let rightSideString = """
      },"followed_by_viewer
      """
            guard
                let leftSideRange = htmlString.range(of: leftSideString)
            else {
                print("couldn't find left range")
                return
            }
            guard
                let rightSideRange = htmlString.range(of: rightSideString)
            else {
                print("couldn't find right range")
                return
            }
            let rangeOfTheData = leftSideRange.upperBound..<rightSideRange.lowerBound
            valueWeWantToGrab = String(htmlString[rangeOfTheData])
            print(valueWeWantToGrab) // prints the follower count: 19093
        }
    }
}
```

One final tip in case you come from a web development background (which is what I am guessing): `var`s in Swift are different from `var`s in JavaScript. In JavaScript, the redeclaration would have overridden the previous value of `valueWeWantToGrab` and your code would have worked. However, in Swift, this actually declares a new, different variable in the local scope of the getter function. Have a look at [the Swift docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html#ID356) to find out more about how variable declarations work in Swift.